# how to read values from the property file in spring-boot and use it in asserting the tests

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, rest-assured

There is a property file which is being read when displaying errors in the response.

For asserting the error messages in my test code(which is Java+rest-assured) I have to read the expected value from the property file and assert on that.

Now how can I do that? what should be my approach for reading from property file and asserting the expected and actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have configured your test classes like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringSampleAppApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class MyTests
```

You should be able to access the properties as you would do in your application, i.e. injecting an instance of MesssageSource, like this:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
...
messageSource.getMessage(messageKey, args, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

Comment: @Sanjay...I tried your suggestion but its not working...there is a base class where I am using all the annotataions and then extending that class to the tests classes. This is how I am giving the property file : @PropertyScanner(classpath:test\src\propertyFile:properties)

Comment: I also use a base class only. I didn't need to use any `@PropertyScanner`. I'm able to inject my beans in test classes, and so injecting `messageSource`, as above, should work, I think. Are you not able to inject that? What error you are getting?